# Canvas - Multiplying triangles to form a draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm making a project using canvas and svg. I've drawn a pattern using canvas with 4 triangles. The problem is, I now need to make those 4 triangles smaller in order to insert more of the on my screen. Here's my code.

```
function telaGeraTriangulo(corFundo,corLinha, x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2){
        pintor.fillStyle=corFundo;
        pintor.strokeStyle=corLinha;
        pintor.beginPath();
        pintor.moveTo(x0,y0);
        pintor.lineTo(x1,y1);
        pintor.lineTo(x2,y2);
        pintor.closePath();
        pintor.stroke();
        pintor.fill();
     }
```

then I just call my function in the script like so:

```
    telaGeraTriangulo("#449779","#449779", 250,250,0,0,0,500);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#E6B569","#E6B569", 250,250,0,0,500,0);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#AA8D49","#AA8D49", 250,250,501,0,500,500);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#013D55","#013D55", 250,250,0,500,500,500);
```

This draws the triangles with my desire coordenates. Now I need to fill my screen with more of these. I'll post some screenshots.

What I have done:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SThYW.jpg

What I need to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q07in.jpg

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `canvas.scale()` and `canvas.translate()` to draw scaled down versions of your original design at different positions.

You will probably want to use `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()` to reset the transform back to normal afterwards.

So assuming I understand your code correctly, you will want to do something like:

```
function drawHalfSizeGrid()
{
  pintor.scale(0.5, 0.5);
  for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
      pintor.save();
      pintor.translate(i*250, j*250);
      drawSquare();
      pintor.restore();
    }
  }
}

function drawSquare() {
  telaGeraTriangulo("#449779","#449779", 250,250,0,0,0,500);
  telaGeraTriangulo("#E6B569","#E6B569", 250,250,0,0,500,0);
  telaGeraTriangulo("#AA8D49","#AA8D49", 250,250,501,0,500,500);
  telaGeraTriangulo("#013D55","#013D55", 250,250,0,500,500,500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a function to draw a single triangle.

Create a function to draw a single square of triangles.

```
function drawSquare(x, y, size) {
    var centerX = x + size / 2;
    var centerY = y + size / 2;
    var farX = x + size;
    var farY = y + size;
    telaGeraTriangulo("#449779", "#449779", centerX, centerY, x, y, x, farY);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#E6B569", "#E6B569", centerX, centerY, x, y, farX, y);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#AA8D49", "#AA8D49", centerX, centerY, farX, y, farX, farY);
    telaGeraTriangulo("#013D55", "#013D55", centerX, centerY, x, farY, farX, farY);
}
```

Create a function to draw multiple squares.

```
function drawMultipleSquares(x, y, size, horizontalCount, verticalCount) {
    for (var i = 0; i < horizontalCount; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < verticalCount; j++) {
            drawSquare(x + i * size, y + j * size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Call the function with the desired location, size, and number of squares.

```
drawMultipleSquares(0, 0, 100, 4, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm, its short and simple to understand! I couldnt be more grateful, it's what I needed, however, I still need one more thing that I cant figure it out, the max numbers of squares per line has to be 30. I was changing the size, horizontal and vertical value, and I did manage to draw 30 squares per line, but they dont fill my 500x500 canvas. Any idea of what I should do?

Sorry if its hard for me to explain my problem, this is my first year at HTML programming

Comment: If you want 30 squares per line then divide canvas width by 30 to get the size of a square. Then divide canvas width and height by size to get horizontal and vertical counts.